# Generating several variable outputs without using if statements

Tags: python, string, variables, if-statement, int

I'm here not with a question of specific coding, but more of a query on how to generate specific variable outputs without using if statements.

To make it clearer here is an example: Mr. Smith is giving out 5 point quizzes that are graded on a scale of 5-A, 4-B, 3-C, 2-D, 1-E, 0-F. Create a program which accepts a the quiz score (1-5) as an input and prints out the corresponding grade without using if statements.

So hopefully that makes my dilemma much clearer. I'm looking for a way to associate the grade (A-F) with the corresponding quiz score (1-5) without using an if statement. I'm still fairly new to python and you could call me a slow learner but any help is appreciated!

Comment: @jamylak yes it is associated with my homework, but the example is not specific to my assignment, hopefully that isn't a problem?

Comment: Hint: there are many ways... dictionary, list, tuple being the obvious ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
'FEDCBA'[score]
```

This works by taking the character at position `score` in the string `'FEDCBA'`: `F` is at position `0`, `E` is at position `1` and so on.

For example:

```
In [1]: 'FEDCBA'[0]
Out[1]: 'F'

In [2]: 'FEDCBA'[5]
Out[2]: 'A'
```

Comment: While I'm not too clear on what the statements 'In[1]:' and 'Out[1]:' refer to, I got the just of your answer through using "FEDCBA" as an entire string and making use of their positions. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Jertise: `In` and `Out` are not part of the code; they are IPython prompts that show what I've typed in and what it printed out. See http://ipython.org/

Comment: Ahh, I get it..sorry, this is still very new to me, but your answer is still appreciated, and I was able to get a simple yet efficient code.

Comment: -1 I find this to be an ugly hack.  A dictionary is the one obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

The most straightforward and flexible way is to use a **dictionary**:

```
>>> score_grade_mapping = {6: 'A+', 5: 'A', 4: 'B', 3: 'C', 2: 'D', 1: 'E', 0: 'F'}
>>> score_grade_mapping[4]
'B'
>>> score_grade_mapping[6]
'A+'
```

While it is just a sequence of numbers, starting at zero, mapping to individual letters, you can do this more efficiently (though less obviously) with a string, using **string indexing**.

```
>>> score_grade_mapping = 'FEDCBA'
>>> score_grade_mapping[4]
'B'
```

If you needed more than a single letter, but still with a series of scores from zero onwards, you could use a **list** (mutable) or **tuple** (immutable, thus more efficient for such things where you are not changing it) with **indexing**:

```
>>> score_grade_mapping = 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A+'
>>> score_grade_mapping[4]
'B'
>>> score_grade_mapping[6]
'A+'
```

Answer (score 2):

use dictionary:

```
dic={5:'A',4:'B',3:'C',2:'D',1:'E',0:'F'}
score=int(input())
grade=dic.get(score,'invalid input')
print(grade)
```

Comment: I get a lot of answers referring me to use dictionaries on almost all of my questions, but the problem is I didn't learn through my work and exercises on the function of dictionaries. I blame my text, but I still appreciate your answer, as I kind of get a sense of what dictionary does now.

Comment: get a basic idea about them here :http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries